# Jquery form validation making password fields require if any one is having any value

Tags: jquery

I have two password fields

pwd1 and pwd2

I am using jquery plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

How to make pwd1 and pwd2 to be required and equal if and only if any one of the field is non-empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `equalTo` rule, as @voigtan suggests, but store the `required` rule in the element's class. That will allow you to enable or disable the rule at will:

```
var $passwords = $("input:password");
$passwords.change(function() {
    if ($passwords.filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0;
    }).length > 0) {
        $passwords.addClass("required");
    } else {
        $passwords.removeClass("required");
    }
});
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        "confirm-password": {
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }
});
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GH8rD/).

Answer (score 0):

Havent used it but: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ have the following:

```
rules: {
    //...
    password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    },
    confirm_password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        equalTo: "#password"
    },
    //...
}
```

in the rule object

Comment: that makes both field to be required. I want them to be required if any one is field .

Comment: @Vivek Goel cant you add the rule with rules("add", rules); on the change event on pwd1/pwd2 if the changed value isnt ""?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an additional method to do that! See http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/additional-methods.js